# Admin toolbar shows up when not logged in

Tags: admin

I'm running into a Major trouble.

Today I found out that when visiting a specific URL on my website, the admin toolbar shows up. Also for people who are not logged in. It appears that the visitor is logged in, but that's not true. All the links in the toolbar go to a 404 page. However, important information is being shown, like how many plugins need an update and even my login name.

Is anyone familiar with this?

Since it is a corporate website, I need a fix as soon as possible. (due to security reasons I won't post the exact url in public)

Comment: Never seen this but I assume that your theme or a plugin is doing something wrong, or caching is causing trouble maybe. Do you have this problem with a bundled theme like Twenty Fourteen?

Comment: Also: Does it only happen on your machine and the same browser you have been logged in before?

Comment: @kraftner Yes it happened on other machines with other browsers (including my smartphone) which have never been used to log in.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Thanks! It was the W3 Total Cache plugin that I use. I've found that the CSS file that styled the toolbar on that specific page was in a cache folder of this plugin. So problem solved.

Comment: you like display adminbar when user not login? ya user login then display admin bar please specify?

Comment: Like I said, I don't want the toolbar when users are NOT logged in. And as you can read, it didn't only show on users who were not logged in, also on regular visitors of my site. Anyway, I found what caused this problem, check below

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the W3 Total Cache plugin caused this problem. I tried removing the toolbar via CSS by using `display:none;`. When this didn't worked, I found that the CSS that styled the toolbar was in one of the cache folders of this plugin.